# Gnu parallel not utilizing all the CPU

Tags: linux, bash, python, shell

I have a simple python script that read from stdin (a single line), do some processing (string parsing, no IO involved) and output to stdout

```
e.g. python parse.py < in.txt > out.txt
```

I have an `in.txt` which is around 200GB in size, and I use parallel to speed it up (I have 8 CPU cores).

```
cat in.txt | parallel -j8 -N1 --pipe python parse.py
```

What I observed the CPU is they are not fully utilizing, e.g.

```
%Cpu0  :  9.1 us, 22.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 68.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 27.3 us, 13.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 59.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 14.3 us, 71.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 14.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 14.3 us, 28.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 57.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  : 14.3 us, 38.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 47.6 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  :  4.8 us, 23.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 71.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  : 15.0 us, 20.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 65.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  : 23.8 us, 19.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 57.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

And

```
ps ax | grep python
```

I got

```
12450 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash -c               sh -c 'dd bs=1 count=1 of=/tmp/2NQLo8j4qy.chr 2>/dev/null';              test ! -s "/tmp/2NQLo8j4qy.chr" && rm -f "/tmp/2NQLo8j4qy.chr" && exec true;              (cat /tmp/2NQLo8j4qy.chr; rm /tmp/2NQLo8j4qy.chr; cat - ) | (python parse.py);
12453 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash -c               sh -c 'dd bs=1 count=1 of=/tmp/zYnfr4Ss8H.chr 2>/dev/null';              test ! -s "/tmp/zYnfr4Ss8H.chr" && rm -f "/tmp/zYnfr4Ss8H.chr" && exec true;              (cat /tmp/zYnfr4Ss8H.chr; rm /tmp/zYnfr4Ss8H.chr; cat - ) | (python parse.py);
12456 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash -c               sh -c 'dd bs=1 count=1 of=/tmp/wlrI14juYz.chr 2>/dev/null';              test ! -s "/tmp/wlrI14juYz.chr" && rm -f "/tmp/wlrI14juYz.chr" && exec true;              (cat /tmp/wlrI14juYz.chr; rm /tmp/wlrI14juYz.chr; cat - ) | (python parse.py);
12459 ?        S      0:00 /bin/bash -c               sh -c 'dd bs=1 count=1 of=/tmp/cyArLNBTTm.chr 2>/dev/null';              test ! -s "/tmp/cyArLNBTTm.chr" && rm -f "/tmp/cyArLNBTTm.chr" && exec true;              (cat /tmp/cyArLNBTTm.chr; rm /tmp/cyArLNBTTm.chr; cat - ) | (python parse.py);
12461 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python
15211 ?        S    144:22 perl /usr/bin/parallel -j8 -N1 --pipe python parse.py
```

Every time I run `ps ax | grep python` I got different temp files, I assume CPU is wasted in dealing with these temp files? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are the specifications of the CPU in use? `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Mark's answer is correct and fully supported, you might want to give a new feature a spin.

```
cat file | parallel --pipe ...
```

maxes out at around 100 MB/s.

The new experimental option --pipepart delivers > 2 GB/s, but requires in.txt to be a real (seekable) file:

```
parallel -a in.txt --block 100M --pipepart python parse.py
```

Comment: Yes, Mark's answer helps, but your command is a faster fix, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `-N1` is causing one process to be created per line. You are seeing the overhead of parallel set up. You should alter the python script to handle more than one line. Then `cat in.txt | parallel --pipe python parse.py` should make full use of the CPUs.