# How to improve the efficiency of gnu parallel to read from a compressed stream?

Tags: unix, unix-shell, parallel-computing

Is another question extended from the previous one [1]

I have a compressed file and stream them to feed into a python program, e.g.

```
bzcat data.bz2 | parallel --no-notice -j16 --pipe python parse.py > result.txt
```

The parse.py can read from stdin continusuoly and print to stdout

My ec2 instance is 16 cores but from the top command it is showing 3 to 4 load average only.

From the `ps`, I am seeing a lot of stuffs like..

```
sh -c 'dd bs=1 count=1 of=/tmp/7D_YxccfY7.chr 2>/dev/null';
```

I know I can improve using the `-a in.txt`to improve performance, but with my case I am streaming from bz2 (I cannot exact it since I don't have enought disk space)

How to improve the efficiency for my case?

[1] [Gnu parallel not utilizing all the CPU](https://serverfault.com/questions/595114/gnu-parallel-not-utilizing-all-the-cpu)

Answer (score 0):

Increase the block size:

```
--block 100m
```

Comment: Write more, how does it work.